# How do I use an existing certificate to connect to a server to get a JSON response with HTTPS in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to get a JSON response back from an API call with a GET request. I know the server is protected and the application needs a certificate to be able to make a call.

Right now I have a `certificate.pfx` file which I can import in my browser and get responses back from the server.

How can I do this with my Java application so the application uses the certificate to connect to the server and get responses back?

```
   package controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import models.UserProfile;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import saleem.orm.utils.HibernateUtil;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    public Result login() {
        RequestJSON();
        return ok(views.html.login.render());
    }

    public Result register() {
        return ok(views.html.register.render());
    }

    public Result start() {
        return ok(views.html.start.render());
    }

    public void RequestJSON() {

        try {
            // Censored the URL for the question
            URL url = new URL("https://");
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.connect();
            String res = con.getResponseMessage();
            con.disconnect();
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Stacktrace when my application tries to connect to the server:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1689)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
        at controllers.HomeController.RequestJSON(HomeController.java:56)
        at controllers.HomeController.login(HomeController.java:24)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(Routes.scala:193)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$6.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:142)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$6.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:141)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$3$$anon$4$$anon$5.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:115)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:119)
        at play.http.DefaultActionCreator$1.call(DefaultActionCreator.java:33)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction.$anonfun$apply$8(JavaAction.scala:175)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:672)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:431)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.$anonfun$execute$1(HttpExecutionContext.scala:64)
        at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:59)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:302)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.dispatchOrAddCallbacks(Promise.scala:276)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.map(Promise.scala:146)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:672)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:176)
        at play.api.mvc.Action.$anonfun$apply$4(Action.scala:82)
        at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.$anonfun$mapFuture$4(Accumulator.scala:168)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
        at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.$anonfun$mapFuture$3(Accumulator.scala:168)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:85)
        at play.api.libs.streams.StrictAccumulator.run(Accumulator.scala:199)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$runAction$4(AkkaHttpServer.scala:417)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
        at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.$anonfun$transformWith$3(FastFuture.scala:51)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:448)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:48)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:227)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1671)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
        ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

As per the aforementioned exception, server identity is not getting validated by the client. The client has to validate the incoming server certificate during `SSL handshake` process and for that client rely on the root certificates (certificates used in signing the server certificate) present in the java truststore. Also, It's up to the client which truststore they want to use while making the connection.

Following is for adding the certificates for default java truststore i.e `cacerts`.

Locate the java truststore on your system. Usually, on windows os, it can be found at `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. You can access this truststore using the default password `changeit`. Add the certificates into the store by using utilities such as `keytool`